# How to provide read-only access to a subset of library documents?

Tags: document-library, permissions, sharepoint-enterprise

Let's say we have a library of Dept docs with R/W access for Dept members. 
- Some of the Dept docs need to be shared but not all, only that are "ready" to be shared as READONLY to Dept Visitors. 
- The docs may continued to be edited after they are shared and hence it helps to have the verison history in one place. 
- We want to avoid item level security at all costs.

We have considered the following options:
- We created another library, say Shared docs, where read-only permissions are granted to Dept Visitors. We then added links to the original documents from the Dept library. Since they are links, the latest content is always available. Buuut, the Visitors can't access the documents since they don't have READ permissions on the Dept library.
- We considered giving READ permission to the Dept library but then all the docs are exposed to Visitors vs. a subset
- Duplicating content seems to be the only other option where a subset of docs and possibly specific versions have to be copied from one library to another and versioning maintained at both places.

Any way to meet the requirements without item level security and content duplication?

Thanks, Sachin

Answer (score 1):

Folders, you can have a single document library with a working folder where general users do not have access (broken permissions inheritance).  When the files are ready, move them out of the folder into the root of the library where the visitors do have access.

Comment: With folders, how is it different from using two libraries? Do we have the same trade-offs in terms of moving or duplicating documents between 2 folders and 2 libraries?